# Running commands in C# is not giving any output

Tags: c#

When I am running `relog` command from command prompt, I am getting the output without any issue.

[image]

Now when I am trying to run command using C# code, I am not getting any output. What could be the issue?

```
public static string Bash()
    {
        var process = new Process()
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "cmd.exe",
                WorkingDirectory = @"C:\blgs",
                Arguments = "relog.exe sample.blg",
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
            }
        };
        process.Start();
        string result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        process.WaitForExit();
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: When you say your not geting any output are you saying that the string 'result' is empty?

Comment: Try running `relog.exe` as the filename and `sample.blg` as the argument. Don't run relog via `cmd.exe`. What happens now is that relog gives its output to the `cmd.exe` you invoke, and cmd swallows it.

Comment: Thanks @gnud. It's working.

Comment: Actually, I think the call to cmd.exe failed completely. If you want cmd.exe to run another program "directly", you have to give it the `/c` switch. It might work if you say `cmd.exe` as the filename and `/c relog.exe sample.blg` as the argument. But there's no reason to go via `cmd` in this case, better to run the actual program directly.